# C++ Why are my struct members changing values with the context?

Tags: c++, struct

I am running into some strange behavior and I am not sure what is causing it.

Depending on the context in which I access the members of a struct I am getting very different values back.

Here is the relevant code defining the structs:

```
struct ScreenTriangle
{
    int type;
    Vector2 points[3];
    Vector4 verts[3];
    Vector4 norms[3];

    ScreenTriangle() {}
    ScreenTriangle(Triangle, Matrix, int, int);
    bool split(ScreenTriangle&);
};

struct Vector2
{
    double x;
    double y;
    ... //Lots of functions
};

struct Vector4
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double w;
    ... //Lots of functions
};
```

At the end of the constructor for the ScreenTriangle struct I added some debug code to print out the values:

```
ScreenTriangle::ScreenTriangle(Triangle triangle, Matrix matrix, int width, int height)
{
    ... //Initialization logic
    //DEBUG
    fprintf(stderr, "\tConstruct Triangle\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\t\tpoints\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", points[0].x, points[0].y);
    fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", points[1].x, points[1].y);
    fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", points[2].x, points[2].y);
}
```

This is the last thing done in the constructor, so I would think those would be the correct values. Here is the code that actually creates the ScreenTriangles:

```
...
ScreenTriangle first = ScreenTriangle(triangle, m_cam[best_image], image_width, image_height);
//DEBUG
fprintf(stderr, "\tScreenTriangle pre\n");
fprintf(stderr, "\t\tPoints\n");
fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", first.points[0].x, first.points[0].y);
fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", first.points[1].x, first.points[1].y);
fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", first.points[2].x, first.points[2].y);
    if(first.type == OTHER_TRIANGLE)
    {
        ScreenTriangle second;
        first.split(second); //Modifies the ScreenTriangle calling the function and instantiates a new ScreenTriangle on the passed reference
        //DEBUG
        fprintf(stderr, "\tScreenTriangle post top\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\tPoints\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", first.points[0].x, first.points[0].y);
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", first.points[1].x, first.points[1].y);
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", first.points[2].x, first.points[2].y);
        fprintf(stderr, "\tScreenTriangle post bottom\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\tPoints\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", second.points[0].x, second.points[0].y);
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", second.points[1].x, second.points[1].y);
        fprintf(stderr, "\t\t\t%f, %f\n", second.points[2].x, second.points[2].y);
        ...
```

As you can see immediately after the constructor finishes I again print out the data. I would expect these to be the same, but they are definitely not. I thought maybe the data had been corrupted somehow so I added some output in the middle of the split method to output the values of the triangle before the split, and the values of the two triangles resulting from the split. I then also output these values from the main program just to sanity check the results. The results are far from sane.

```
//stderr, NOT CODE, couldn't figure out how to format it otherwise
Construct Triangle
    points
        470.142394, 436.976659
        470.353823, 437.546349
        470.366987, 440.896491
ScreenTriangle pre
    Points
        0.000776, 4734553876061397887934347591916838705351250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
        28381368350.827759, -19400122721264338832825401151226542897600390000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
        0.000000, 0.000000
Split triangle
    Original
        points
            470.142394, 436.976659
            470.353823, 437.546349
            470.366987, 440.896491
        ...
    new_point
        470.175036, 437.546349
    ...
    Top Triangle
        points
            470.142394, 436.976659
            470.175036, 437.546349
            470.353823, 437.546349
    Bot Triangle
        points
            470.175036, 437.546349
            470.353823, 437.546349
            470.366987, 440.896491
ScreenTriangle post top
    Points
        0.000776, 4734553876061397887934347591916838705351250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
        -29450462837259105633893654055197308700574950000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000, -19400122721262697099929384820740204292408740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
        28381368350.836658, -19400122721264338832825401151226542897600390000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
ScreenTriangle post bottom
    Points
        -29450456430284346305088130197738746199887030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000, -19400122721262697099929384820740204292408740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
        28381368350.836658, -19400122721264338832825401151226542897600390000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
        0.000000, 0.000000
```

I am very confused as to what is happening. Why, when I check the values from within the ScreenTriangle struct are they one thing, are they then different when I check the values in the very next command from outside the struct?

The values apparently have not changed since they show the original values when I check them again from a function within the ScreenTriangle struct, but when I check them again immediately afterwards, from outside the struct, I get these ridiculous results.

I wondered if perhaps it had something to do with my system. I was compiling and running it through Cygwin on a Windows 7 machine, so I pulled the code to a machine running Fedora (v20 I think) and tried again but with the same strange results.

What am I missing here? Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: It would help greatly if you had a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I cannot replicate your output using your supplied code as a base (it works as expected). Something else in your code that you haven't posted is likely causing the issue.

Comment: Ah, I have not heard of MCVEs before. The program this is in is quite large and complex, I tried to include all the code relevant to the issue.

Comment: @SoggyPancakes now you have heard of them, so try to make one. It may turn out that in the process of making one , you discover what the problem was.  As you can see from the answers posted so far,  it's difficult to debug a program when you can only see little bits and pieces of it.

Comment: Add a function that does debug output of a triangle, instead of copy-pasting blocks of fprintf lines everywhere

Comment: That occurred to me as I was writing the question. It is quite annoying and obfuscates the meaning of the code.

Comment: I am unable to right now, but I will try to make an MCVE later today for this problem.

Comment: I found the issue. After stepping through it statement by statement with the debugger and not understanding why the values changed between the end of the constructor and the calling context I printed out the memory locations for each member of the struct. Turns out there was a #pragma pack(2) in one header that was called after main file, but before the header for this class. Adding #pragma pack(8) fixed the problem. There wasn't enough information in my post to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the vectors before defining them. Definition of Vector2 and Vector4 should be before definition of ScreenTriangle. That may cause the problem

Comment: Sorry, this was a result of my summarizing my code. Each of these structs is defined in a different header file and have accompanying cpp file implementations. If this were the problem it would not compile and I would not be able to get any output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Does it fix it if you change:

```
ScreenTriangle first = ScreenTriangle(triangle, m_cam[best_image], image_width, image_height);
```

To:

```
ScreenTriangle first(triangle, m_cam[best_image], image_width, image_height);
```

Perhaps there is something in `Vector2` that prevent the memberwise copy of the structs from occurring properly (your original code).

Comment: Changing that did not affect the output. Preventing memberwise copy.. I am afraid I do not understand what you mean. Do you mean to suggest something about Vector2 might make it so that when I do first.points[*] it does not properly copy to the scope where it is then trying to access the x member within the copied Vector2 struct?

Comment: Your code creates a temporary instance of ScreenTriangle, then uses the default operator= method (since you have not provided one) which supposedly copies all the data members including Vector2 to the "first" instance.  My code constructs the "first" instance of ScreenTriangle directly, thus eliminating the copy part (which I thought might have been the problem).  Can you run the code in a debugger and see if it shows the same problem as the fprintf?

Comment: It does indeed. I am quite confused. Stepping through it at the very end of the constructor it has the correct values, then when I step again out of the constructor and I check the ScreenTriangle the values are all messed up.